# useState polyfill, is this correct?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, polyfills

Trying to write a custom implementation of useState. Let's say only for a single value.

```js
function useMyState(initVal){
  const obj = {
    value: initVal,
    get stateValGet() {
      return this.value
    },
    set stateValSet(val) {
      this.value = val
    }
  };
  const setVal = (val) => {
    obj.stateValSet = val
  }
  return [obj.stateValGet, setVal]
}
```

Doesn't seem to work though, can anyone tell why?
Unable to crack this.

It returns this [, <function_setter>]
So if you try to run this setVal method, it does trigger the setter. But getter never gets called upon the updation.

Comment: `useState` can't really be substituted with something custom like this, at least not in React itself. I'm not seeing the point of the `obj` object either

Answer (score 3):

`useState`'s functionality can't really be polyfilled or substituted with your own custom implementation, because it not only stores state, but it also *triggers a component re-render* when the state setter is called. Triggering such a re-render is only possible with access to React internals, which the surface API available to us doesn't have access to.

`useState` can't be replaced with your own implementation unless that implementation also uses `useState` itself in order to get the component it's used in to re-render when the state setter is called.

You could create your own custom implementation *outside* of React, though, one which simulates a re-render by calling a function again when the state setter is called.

```js
const render = () => {
  console.log('rendering');
  const [value, setValue] = useMyState(0);
  document.querySelector('.root').textContent = value;
  const button = document.querySelector('.root')
    .appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
  button.addEventListener('click', () => setValue(value + 1));
  button.textContent = 'increment';
};
const useMyState = (() => {
  let mounted = false;
  let currentState;
  return (initialValue) => {
    if (!mounted) {
      mounted = true;
      currentState = initialValue;
    }
    return [
      currentState,
      (newState) => {
        currentState = newState;
        render();
      }
    ];
  };
})();
render();
```

```html
<div class="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Every state manager that wants to interact with React has to find a way to **connect** to React lifecycle, in order to be able to trigger re-renders on state change. `useState` hook internally uses `useReducer`:
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/16.8.6/packages/react-dom/src/server/ReactPartialRendererHooks.js#L254

That's why I made this naive implementation of `useState` based on JavaScript Proxies and a `useReducer` dummy dispatch just to force a re-render when state changes.

It's naive, but that's what `valtio` is based on.

Consider that the power of proxies would make it possible to trigger re-renders by mutating state directly, that's what happens in `valtio`!

```js
import { useReducer, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';

export const useMyState = (_state) => {
  // FORCE RERENDER
  const [, rerender] = useReducer(() => ({}));
  const forceUpdate = useCallback(() => rerender({}), []);

  // INITIALIZE STATE AS A MEMOIZED PROXY
  const { proxy, set } = useMemo(() => {
    const target = {
      state: _state,
    };
    // Place a trap on setter, to trigger a component rerender
    const handler = {
      set(target, prop, value) {
        console.log('SETTING', target, prop, value);
        target[prop] = value;
        forceUpdate();
        return true;
      },
    };

    const proxy = new Proxy(target, handler);

    const set = (d) => {
      const value = typeof d === 'function' ? d(proxy.state) : d;
      if (value !== proxy.state) proxy.state = value;
    };

    return { proxy, set };
  }, []);

  return [proxy.state, set];
};
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-33fpbk?file=src%2FApp.js